# Popover in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-popover

I want to provide a set of additional information in my bootstrap template. I want to have a set of terms and conditions with a plain english popover for certain key terms.

I've included all the correct links to the CDN and I get a popup from just the below code but when I view it as a whole page this stops working and just sends me back to the top of the page. Is there something that I need to bear in mind when doing this? I've spent days trying to tweak this to work?

Thank you

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popover.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<aside class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h2>An example of what we will do</h2>
    <hr class="light">

    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>

  </div>
</aside>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: try with removing the `jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js` since You've already included jquery from `vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @SebastianKrysiak That still doesn't work either

Comment: what is Your console output?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
    at popover.js:1
creative.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: a(...).affix is not a function
    at creative.min.js:6
    at creative.min.js:6
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set right the CDN file. Please set the right path to the jquery library and try to remove the file `jquery.slim` if it's not required.

Checkout the snippet

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<aside class="bg-dark">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <h2>An example of what we will do</h2>
    <hr class="light">

    <a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the popover">Toggle popover</a>

  </div>
</aside>
```